# Bash and variables substitution

Tags: bash

I use this to generate svn logs for a specific user:

```
svn log | sed -n '/bob/,/-----$/ p'
```

which works fine. Now I would like to use a parameter/variable for the user:

```
USER="bob"
svn log | sed -n '/$USER/,/-----$/ p'
```

but it just give an empty log. How do I pass a parameter to the above command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
USER="bob"
svn log | sed -n '/'$USER'/,/-----$/ p'
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is to use double quotes so that the bash variable can be expanded:

```
USER="bob"
svn log | sed -n "/$USER/,/-----$/p"
```

Adding more single quotes to "insert" a bash variable (as per the accepted answer) is not best practice. HTH.

Comment: +1 a cleaner solution. I think it would also be nice to explain why that final `$` doesn't get expanded, or when it might need to be escaped

Answer (score 0):

try:

svn log | sed -n '/"$USER"/,/-----$/ p'